# Select users from AD randomly

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We've been tasked with creating a process to review random employee's web traffic on a quarterly basis. I have started a script in Powershell that selects 10 random users from a specific OU, but I'm still getting some unneeded data. I need help filtering down the list further. The output gives me users that have been disabled and left in the OU as well as PRN employees that haven't signed on in a long time. I would like to search AD accounts that has an email address & a logon, modified within the last 3 months. Here is an example of the code I have so far.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=ouname,ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=suffix" -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object{Get-Random} | select -First 10
```

[Edit: Question Answered]

Here is my final script, added `$_.passwordlastset` as a search attribute since this will pickup users that have changed their password in the last 90 days.

```
$DateFrom = (get-Date).AddDays(-90)

Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter {enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase "ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=suffix" | where { $_.passwordlastset -gt $DateFrom -and $_.mail -ne $null } | Sort-Object {Get-Random} | select name, sAMAccountName -First 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ADUser -Properties name, mail, lastlogondate -Filter {enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase "ou=ouname,ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=suffix" | select name, mail, lastlogondate | where { $_.lastlogondate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -and $_.mail -ne $null }
```

Here a start.

Comment: I was able to get what I needed from this snippet. Only thing I changed was made the properties to wild card `-Properties *`, added `Sort-Object {Get-Random} | Select -First 10` I will post my final script above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$timeFrame = (get-Date).AddDays(-90)

get-aduser -SearchBase 'ou=ouname,ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=suffix' -Filter * -Properties * | 
    Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -gt $timeFrame -and $_.mail -ne $null} |
    Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object{Get-Random} | select -First 10
```

Comment: `WhenChanged` might not be the best indicator here - if an account was disabled in the last 90 days it would show up

Comment: Sure. You can use the whenChanged property if you prefer. But just disabling the account counts as a change so it would still show up. If you want to exclude disabled accounts then the best way to do that is filter them out. So now your code looks like this (I posted another answer). Or you can use LastLogontimeStamp.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `-Filter` value:

```
# LastLogontimeStamp is not guaranteed to be updated on every login, so 30 days + 14 days margin
$threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-44).ToFileTime()
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true -and LastLogontimeStamp -gt $threshold} -SearchBase "ou=ouname,ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=suffix" | Sort-Object {Get-Random} | Select Name -First 10
```

This filter will ensure that AD only returns Enabled users and that their `lastLogontimeStamp` value has been updated within the last month and a half

Comment: If `LastLogontimeStamp` doesn't accurately retrieve users with a login in the given time period, do you suggest querying a different property?

Answer (score 1):

This will do everythign the OP stated:

```
$timeFrame = (get-Date).AddDays(-90)
get-aduser -SearchBase 'YourOU,DC=Domain,DC=com' -Filter * -Properties * | 
Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -lt $timeFrame -and $_.mail -ne $null -and $_.Enabled -eq $true} |
Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object{Get-Random} | select -First 10
```

This should meet all the OPs checkpoints via the snippets:

"I would like to search AD accounts that has an email address"
`$_.mail -ne $null`

"& a logon"
`$_.Enabled -eq $true`

"modified within the last 3 months"
`$_.whenChanged -lt $timeFrame`

Comment: I tried this and I get test accounts that have never logged on. I noticed you changed `$_.whenChanged -gt` to `$_.whenChagned -lt`

Comment: Yea it was a typo. OP wanted "within" the last 3 months, not beyond it. Oversight on my part in my original posting that I corrected.